# Controlling multiple Kibana visualizations without Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I wanted to view multiple visualizations as similar to Kibana Dashboards (but without using Dashboards). I wish to control multiple embedded visualization through a singular search filter (as done in Dashboards).

As much as I love dashboards, it's hard to do UI customization into my APP with one large embedded dashboard iframe. What is my best course of action to implement this use case into my app?

I'm using Kibana 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You can embed individual visualisations from Visualise tab instead of single dashboard embed.

Comment: This won't let you control all the visualizations together.